# How to get Jupyter notebook to start under specific anaconda environment and under specific directory?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, jupyter-notebook

The default directory of Jupyter notebook is the `C:\Users\User Name\`
I want to open several Jupyter notebooks in different folders at the same time (some of them in portable drives). additionally, I want to run Jupyter under specific Anaconda environment, with specific libraries and version of python.

I tried until I found the easiest and fastest solution for Windows which I will post in the answers below for the benefit of others.

I have provided the solution for windows, so I hope that others can add similar solutions for Mac and Linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to make a batch file (`*.bat`) with the following commands:

```
REM # A batch file to run Jupyter notebook  on the current folder 

REM # This is to switch to the current directory
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0

REM # If you need special Anaconda environment, replace the py3 name.
REM # If you want to run on the default environment, remove the line.
call activate py3

REM # It is important to add the 'call' 
call jupyter notebook

REM # The pause command is to keep the command window active.
pause
```

If you do not want to run a special Anaconda environment, remove the line `call activate py3`. and if you want to activate different environment, replace the `py3` by its name.

Finally, you have to save the commands above to a text file, rename it to `LaunchJupyterHere.bat` or any name of your choice, and ***place a copy of it in each folder you want to launch Jupyter in***. once you want to launch Jupyter, double-click it, it will open a browser window pointing to the current directory, and under the specific environment.

Best regards

Comment: `cd /d %~dp0` will change to the drive the batch is being run from, what if your batch sits on a different drive? You need to consider all possibilities. What is the relation to the question to the answer? Where do you answer _"I want to open several Jupyter notebooks in different folders at the same time (some of them in portable drives)"_

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, thanks a lot for your feedback, I have updated the answer to clarify the issue. This was a real problem for me, and I want to share my solution with the respectful community.

Comment: `cd /d %~dp0` fails if the directory of the batch file contains `&` for example `C:\Temp\Jupyter & Anaconda`. In this case `Anaconda` would be interpreted as additional command to run after command __CD__. The solution is using `cd /D "%~dp0"`. But this does not work if the batch file is stored on a network share opened using UNC path and the user double clicks on the batch file. In this case `pushd "%~dp0"` would be necessary with a `popd` before `pause`.

Comment: And it would be definitely better to __call__ the batch files `activate` and `jupyter` with specifying complete name of file, i.e. file name + file extension to make the batch file work independent on current value of local environment variable `PATHEXT` and which other files with file name `activate` or `jupyter` exist by chance in directory of the batch file. I would also change `setlocal` to `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` and add an `endlocal` before `pause`.

Comment: Last I would make it possible to omit `pause` if this batch file is called from another batch file with an optional parameter, for example with `if /I not "%~1" == "/nopause" pause`. I just hope that the two called batch files do not define environment variables needed after `endlocal` respectively `pause` as they don't exist anymore after this command respectively batch file execution finished because of `setlocal` command.

Comment: Many thanks @Mofi for your valuable additions, Would you please add an answer with your amendments for the benefits of others?

Answer (score 0):

That may be the easiest windows solution; for me I use Anaconda;
(1) activate the environment.
(2) Open a terminal in that environment via 
[image] Then assuming I want the root to be my E: drive; just->

```
E:
jupyter notebook
```